# How to make mbtiles background transparent?

Tags: transparent, mapbox, tilemill, mbtiles

I am using tilemill to generate mbtiles. Does anybody know how to make mbtiles background transparent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your default style will have a rule like

```
Map {
  background-color:#f00;
}
```

This gives the map a background color. Delete that rule, and the map will not have a background color, and will thus be transparent behind your features.

Comment: I did this, but then some land also gets transparent (for example the Sahara). Is there is a selector for all land? I am not able to find one. My aim is to only have the water transparent.